# How do i check for multiple keywords using cheerio?

Tags: javascript, jquery, express, web-scraping, cheerio

Currently, I am trying to build a scrapper that searches all `<a>` tags for specific keywords like "climate" or "environment." Using cheerio, is it possible to look for multiple keywords so that I get results of multiple keywords?

Here is my code-

```
const PORT = 8000;
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const { response } = require('express');

const app = express();

const articles = [];

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.json('Hello World')
})

app.get('/news',(req,res)=>{
    axios.get('https://www.tbsnews.net/bangladesh/environment/climate-change')
        .then((response)=>{
            const html = response.data;
            const $ = cheerio.load(html);

            $('a:contains("climate")',html).each(function(){
                const title = $(this).text()
                const url = $(this).attr('href')
                articles.push({
                    title,
                    url
                })
            })
            res.json(articles)
        }).catch((err)=>console.log(err));
})

app.listen(PORT,()=>{console.log(`server running on Port ${PORT}`)});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://cheerio.js.org/functions/contains.html) of cheerio, you can use multiple `contains` selectors similarly you would use them in jQuery.

### Logical OR

If you need to match any of the words, just separate the `contains` selectors with a comma.

```
$('a:contains("climate"), a:contains("environment")', html)
```

### Logical AND

If you need to match exactly the two words, add the second `contains` selector right after the first.

```
$('a:contains("climate"):contains("environment")', html)
```